# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, error-handling

This is my code :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sco=int(10011)
    na=""
    for i in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        sco=(sco,score)
        na=na,name
    s = min(sco)
```

But when I am running this code then this comes

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'tuple'
```

I have tried multiple ways like converting variable sco into a list etc...
Please help me out.

Comment: What does ‘sco = (sco, score)’ mean?

Comment: first, the variable sco will store itself inside it and then, it will store score inside it. I have written this so that every time the user inputs score, it will stay inside sco.

Comment: Actually, I am a beginner, so I don't know if this is the best way to do it. Pls suggest me if there's a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

this is because the `sco` variable is assigned to a tuple, you can't determine the minimum of a `float` value and a `tuple`:

if you print the value of sco, the output would get a nested `tuple`:

```
((10011, somefloat), otherfloat) #if we input 2 as the range
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have currently just generates a nested `tuple`, whereas, since you want to collect all the scores, you should simply add them to a `list`:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scores = []      # empty list
    sco = int(10011)
    na=""
    for i in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        scores.append(score)
        sco=(sco,score)
        na=na,name
    s = min(scores)
    print(sco)   # I'm sure you don't want this
    print(s) # I'm sure you want to get the minimum score entered
```